# Writing and reading vector into binary files

Tags: c++

I have a vector:

```
class Element
{
public:

    string pathName;
    ui64 offsitePtr;
    ui64 subPage;

public:

    Element(void);

    ~Element(void);
};

vector<Element> elem;
```

The size of `elem` will be controlled less than 4096 bytes. At the end of the program, I should `fwrite` `elem` into a binary file. The solution I'm using currently is to make a char buffer and write the element in `elem` in it. I don't think it is a good idea. Is there any other good ideas?

Comment: Please add an extra 4 tabs of indentation to your code so that it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Show the code that's relevant to the question (i.e. the `fwrite` call), and state clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Other code is usefulness, the only problem troubles me is how to write string and unsigned long long data in vector into binary file and read it quickly. I will read 4096 bytes at one fread.

Comment: `fread` is buffering anyway, so I don't see big speed gains in reading chunks of 4096 bytes.  You should just read what you need, unless there is some other reason you're using this chunk size.

Comment: I'm writing a b- tree index. I should read a page from desk once. The size of the page is 4096 bytes. So, I should fread 4096 bytes once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you don't write the vector or the `Element`s directly from memory, it's okay.  You'll need to serialize anything that isn't POD (plain old data).  That is in your case: `vector` and `string`.

The vector is easy, because you can just make a function for `Element`.  But you probably want to serialize the vector size:

```
ofstream& WriteVec( ofstream& s, vector<Element> &elem )
{
    size_t size = elem.size();
    s.write( (char*)&size, sizeof(size) );
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        elem(i).Write(s);
    return s;
}
```

For your element:

```
ofstream& Element::Write( ofstream& s )
{
    // Serialize pathName
    size_t strsize = pathName.size();
    s.write( (char*)&strsize, sizeof(strsize) );
    s.write( pathName.c_str(), strsize );

    // Serialize other stuff
    s.write( (char*)&offsitePtr, sizeof(offsitePtr) );
    s.write( (char*)&subPage, sizeof(subPage) );
}
```

And you do something similar when you read.  Will leave you to work that out =)  Note in each case, you're writing a size, and then the data.  When you read, you read in the size, then resize your structure before reading the contents into it.

Oh, and make sure you open the file stream in binary mode.

Comment: char buff[4096] = {0};\n
    int j = 0;\n
    ui32 i = 1;\n
    for (i = 1; i < pageToWrite->countOfElements + 1; i++)\n
    {\n
 memcpy(&buff[j], &pageToWrite->elementInNode[i].pathName, pageToWrite->elementInNode[i].pathName.size());\n
 j += pageToWrite->elementInNode[i].pathName.size();\n
 memcpy(&buff[j], &pageToWrite->elementInNode[i].offsitePtr, 8);\n
 j += 8;\n
 memcpy(&buff[j], &pageToWrite->elementInNode[i].subPage, 8);\n
   j += 8;\n
    }\n

Comment: Sorry, I have pressed the wrong button. Your answer is useful to me. I don't know how to write code in comment, sorry...

Comment: If you want to read/write a buffer first, just turn all my `ofstream::write` calls into `memcpy` and pointer arithmetic (similarly for reading).  You can make a simple `Page` class to handle that, and then make methods on it to read/write it on disk.  You should use unbuffered IO `read` and `write` instead of `fread` and `fwrite` to get better throughput.